# Laravel vapor "This action is unauthorized" with file upload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-vapor

I have set up Laravel Vapor with my RESTFull app using [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum) and now I'm trying to simply upload a file. I'm making a request `POST /vapor/signed-storage-url` and I'm getting:

```json
{
    "message": "This action is unauthorized.",
    ...
}
```

I have created the `UserPolicy` as described in the [docs](https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/resources/storage.html#file-uploads):

```php
class UserPolicy 
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can upload files.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function uploadFiles(User $user): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting `This action is unauthorized`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key piece of information here is that I'm using [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum) to authenticate my users in my app. Laravel's Vapor uses by default the `web` middleware

From the docs I wasn't able to find a way to publish Vapor's configuration.

If we look at [the routes configuration](https://github.com/laravel/vapor-core/blob/2.0/src/DefinesRoutes.php#L24) we will have:

```php
    /**
     * Ensure that Vapor's internal routes are defined.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function ensureRoutesAreDefined()
    {
        if ($this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            return;
        }

        if (config('vapor.signed_storage.enabled', true)) {
            Route::post(
                config('vapor.signed_storage.url', '/vapor/signed-storage-url'),
                Contracts\SignedStorageUrlController::class.'@store'
            )->middleware(config('vapor.middleware', 'web'));
        }
    }
```

Vapor is getting the `vapor.middleware` environment to tell which middleware will be applied to `/vapor/signed-storage-url` route. Since I'm using Sanctum I just had to manually publish Vapor's configuration by creating a `vapor.php` in my `config` folder:

```
- config
-- app.php
-- filesystem.php
-- vapor.php
```

Now in this file you can define your middleware to be set to `auth:sanctum`:

```php
<?php

return [
    // Most of these variables are not necessary as the default from Vapor's 
    // core library is okay for most cases but I will leave here you need to use any of them
    'redirect_to_root' => true,

    'redirect_robots_txt' => true,

    'serve_assets' => [],

    'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum' 
];
```

Now Vapor will start to use the `auth:sanctum` middleware to authenticate the request to `POST /vapor/signed-storage-url`